# How to use DialogService to open a window in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DialogService

```
using RControl.Client.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace RControl.Client.Services;

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public void ShowDialog<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var window = new Window
        {
            Content = Activator.CreateInstance(ViewLocator.GetViewType(typeof(TViewModel))),
            DataContext = viewModel,
        };

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Also ViewLocator

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace RControl.Client;

public static class ViewLocator
{
    private const string ViewSuffix = "View";
    private const string ViewModelSuffix = "ViewModel";

    public static Type GetViewType(Type viewModelType)
    {
        var viewName = viewModelType.Name.Replace(ViewModelSuffix, string.Empty) + ViewSuffix;
        var viewType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == viewName);

        return viewType ?? throw new ArgumentException($"View not found for {viewModelType.Name}.");
    }
}
```

But when using this service in this way

```
[RelayCommand]
private void About()
{
    var viewModel = new AboutViewModel();
    _dialogService.ShowDialog(viewModel);
}
```

An exception is thrown: System.InvalidOperationException: "The Window object must be the root of the tree. You cannot add a Window object as a child object for Visual."

How to achieve the same behavior as with:

```
var window = new AboutView();
window.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your view you're going to show in the window a usercontrol.
Rather than doing all that getviewtype stuff, define datatemplates associating each view with a viewmodel by datatype.

You could build that using metadata in a code generator if you wanted to automate it.

But your window can look like:

```
<Window x:Class="LoginNavigation.LoginNavigationWindow"
    ...
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="450" Width="800"
    Content="{Binding}"
    />
```

That window can be used for any window you need. It's just a shell contains whatever you need to show.

Associate usercontrols:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainViewModel}">
        <local:MainUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Those datatemplates go in a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml.

Then you can new up an instance of that window, set datacontext to a MainViewModel instance and the content of the window is templated into an instance of MainUC.

You may showdialog such a window.

Obviously, retain a reference to it's viewmodel to obtain any user input.